# EC2 Ubuntu 14 default password

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-14.04, xrdp

I have an `EC2` instace running `Ubuntu 14` which I regularly connect to using `SSH`.

Now I'm trying to connect to this instance using Remote Desktop from Windows, as shown [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/592537/can-i-access-ubuntu-from-windows-remotely).

In the Login to `xrdp` form, I typed "ubuntu" as the username, but I don't know what the password is. I've never messed with the password and never needed it. I have tried both "ubuntu" and `""` (blank) but got the same result:

```
xrdp_mm_process_login_response:login failed
```

Does anyone know what the default password of Ubuntu on EC2 is?

If it is either `"Ubuntu"` or `""` then what causes the problem?

Comment: why don't you create another user and create its password and use that to login ?

Comment: When connecting using SSH, do you use a .pem file?

Comment: @Mahdi yes, I do.

Comment: OK, have you edited the `sshd_config` to allow for `PasswordAuthentication`?

Comment: @KushVyas I haven't though about t it. Just tried to create another user and I manage to connect now. Thanks! You're welcome to add it as an answer, and I will vote up and will perhaps accept it if nobody knows what the default password of "ubuntu" is.

Comment: @Mahdi no, I haven't.

Comment: hey @Mahdi I have updated the answer and also mentioned the reason why ubuntu used does not have default password.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not a solution to be precise, but an alternative solution is to login via SSH and create a new `sudo` user with password.

Then use that user to login :)

Edit:
EC2 used SSH keypair authentication for user not password authentication for the user `ubuntu` (default).

Set the password for your current logged in user using the command, `passwd`.

Answer (score 178):

switch to root with:

```
sudo su -
```

Then run:

```
passwd ubuntu
```

It is going to prompt :

```
Enter new UNIX password:
```

So, set your password.

Comment: I got Authentication token manupulation error, password unchanged.

Comment: Work with Ubuntu 22.04 - AWS EC2 December 2022.

Comment: Worked with **Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS - AWS EC2** September 2023