# Unable to log in to EC2 instance - for chef node creation

Tags: amazon-ec2, chef-infra

I am currently learning chef and AWS (new to both of them).

I would like to create a node in [https://manage.chef.io/organizations/su_cheflearning/nodes](https://www.stackoverflow.com/).

The followings are the steps I have done:

1. Go to AWS Console and launch EC2 instance
2. Once it is running, I take public IP address
3. Use gitbash
4. Run this command in chef-repo folder, `knife bootstrap 52.65.76.66 -U ubuntu --sudo -i "D:\DevOpsClass\DevopsClass.pem" -N node01 --chef-license accept`

**Question**

I am having an issue: The issue is I am asked to provide password for ubunt@52.65.76.66 :

I have searched online, some said enter passwd, but none of the suggestions work. I do not launch EC2 with password, so I am not sure what to enter...

1. Checked online knief bootstrap, https://docs-archive.chef.io/release/12-2/chef_client.html
2. checked how to find/ retrieve Ubuntu EC2 password???, [EC2 Ubuntu 14 default password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51667876/ec2-ubuntu-14-default-password)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I know nothing about Chef, but a couple of points:

1. If the IP shown above is your real public IP, you probably want to obscure it.
2. Does the `knife bootstrap` command allow you to configure an SSH key?  EC2 instances do not use password for SSH access, only keys.  If you want the `knife bootstrap` command work, you'll need to configure the ssh key to work with the command.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realise that!! I have deleted the IP. What I have done is launch EC2 with new .pem file and new security group. It works..... I am not sure why... Thanks again!

Comment: This 52.65.76.66 address is from EC2 instance which I have already deleted. Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 0):

I would like to share how I have troubleshoot. It might help other beginner chef learners like myself.

1. Redownload Starter kit from Chef ( Go to Chef Manage -->Under Administration --> Select my organisation --> Actions --> From drop down menu --> select Starter Kit
2. Terminate the existing EC-2. Launch a new EC2 with a new pem file
3. Run knife bootstrap command and I can create the node.